# How to select values within a provided index range from a List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, range

I am a LINQ newbie trying to use it to acheive the following:

I have a list of ints:-

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>(new int[]{1,2,3,3,2,1});
```

Now, I want to compare the sum of the first three elements [index range 0-2] with the last three [index range 3-5] using LINQ. I tried the LINQ Select and Take extension methods as well as the SelectMany method, but I cannot figure out how to say something like

```
(from p in intList  
where p in  Take contiguous elements of intList from index x to x+n  
select p).sum()
```

I looked at the Contains extension method too, but that doesn't see to get me what I want. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) then Take.

```
yourEnumerable.Skip(4).Take(3).Select( x=>x )

(from p in intList.Skip(x).Take(n) select p).sum()
```

Comment: Note that List<T>.GetRange will be more efficient though for larger collections: https://icodeit.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/performance-of-skip-and-take-in-linq-to-objects/, http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/03/29/c.net-little-wonders-skip-and-take.aspx

Comment: That is a good, valid, comment (so valid a couple years ago I had upvoted the answer author below who said the same thing), although the OP asked specifically about LINQ so you can't really guarantee a List<T> as your source. This may have been a simplified version of the real problem in question, where the simplified version was just a hard-coded List<T> (and may really be a query on an object graph or a LINQ to SQL query).

Comment: what's the point of `.Select( x=>x )`? doesn't it actually do nothing in this case?

Answer (score 41):

You can use GetRange()

```
list.GetRange(index, count);
```

Comment: Where is this function at?  .NET 4.5 or something?

Comment: @AdamNofsinger This is under System.Collections.Generic namespace. It came with .Net 2.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Worth noting this is on the `IList` interface, and thus won't work with more common `IEnumerable`. Part of this is to keep people from shooting themselves in the foot performance wise (i.e., if a collection is not indexable in O(1) time, this could take O(n) time, perhaps unexpectedly). Also it returns a new list, rather than being a facade on top of the original list, as LINQ tends to be.

Answer (score 18):

For larger lists, a separate extension method could be more appropriate for performance. I know this isn't necessary for the initial case, but the Linq (to objects) implementation relies on iterating the list, so for large lists this could be (pointlessly) expensive. A simple extension method to achieve this could be:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> IndexRange<TSource>(
    this IList<TSource> source,
    int fromIndex, 
    int toIndex)
{
    int currIndex = fromIndex;
    while (currIndex <= toIndex)
    {
        yield return source[currIndex];
        currIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from .NET 6 it is possible to use [range syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes) for Take method.

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1});

// Starting from index 0 (including) to index 3 (excluding) will select indexes (0, 1, 2)
Console.WriteLine(intList.Take(0..3).Sum()); // {1, 2, 3} -> 6

// By default is first index 0 and can be used following shortcut.
Console.WriteLine(intList.Take(..3).Sum());  // {1, 2, 3} -> 6      


// Starting from index 3 (including) to index 6 (excluding) will select indexes (3, 4, 5)
Console.WriteLine(intList.Take(3..6).Sum()); // {3, 2, 1} -> 6  

// By default is last index lent -1 and can be used following shortcut.
Console.WriteLine(intList.Take(3..).Sum());  // {3, 4, 5} -> 6

// Reverse index syntax can be used. Take last 3 items.
Console.WriteLine(intList.Take(^3..).Sum()); // {3, 2, 1} -> 6

// No exception will be raised in case of range is exceeded.
Console.WriteLine(intList.Take(^100..1000).Sum());
```

So simply put, `intList.Take(..3).Sum()` and `intList.Take(3..).Sum()` can be used with .NET 6.

Answer (score 1):

To filter by specific indexes (not from-to):

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<TSource> ByIndexes<TSource>(this IList<TSource> source, params int[] indexes)
   {        
        if (indexes == null || indexes.Length == 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var i in indexes)
            {
                if (i >= 0 && i < source.Count)
                    yield return source[i];
            }
        }
   }
}
```

For example:

```
string[] list = {"a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5", "f6", "g7", "h8", "i9"};
var filtered = list.ByIndexes(5, 8, 100, 3, 2); // = {"f6", "i9", "d4", "c3"};
```