# How to fast filter objects that satisfy date range condition

Tags: c#, collections, filtering, date-range

I have a large collection of objects

```
public class Restriction
{
    // which days this restriction applies to
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    // valid applicable restriction range
    public int Minimum { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }
}
```

I could then have

```
IList<Restricton> restrictions;
```

and then searching for restrictions that are applied on a particular day

```
restrictions.Where(r => day >= r.From && day <= r.To);
```

### Issue

I suppose using `IList<T>` isn't the best option because I will be doing a lot of searches over these restrictions and every time I would call LINQ method `.Where` the whole collection would be enumerated and filtered.

From the SQL knowledge I have I know that table scan is always worse than an index scan so I would like to apply a similar logic here. Instead of enumerating the whole collection every time I would rather filter in a more intelligent way.

### Question

What would be a better (**faster**) way to enumerate my restrictions so my algorithm wouldn't be enumerating over them every time I'd want to filter out a few?

I was thinking of `IDictionary<K,V>` but it would still need to scan them all because my restrictions are not set per day, but rather per day range.

**What would you suggest?**

Comment: Could the second answer in here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042087/how-to-select-values-within-a-provided-index-range-from-a-list-using-linq

Comment: See: [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

Answer (score 3):

Consider ordering the list by `From` - then you can quickly perform a binary search to find the subset of restrictions which might be applicable in terms of `From`.

You might also want to have a second copy of the list ordered by `To` - then again, you can perform a binary search to find the subset of restrictions which my be applicable in terms of `To`. With both lists, you could perform *both* binary searches, and work out which set is smaller, and only consider that set.

There may well be a much better alternative, but that's a good start, and I don't quite have the mental energy to work out anything better right now :(

Answer (score 2):

What you need are two sorted lists to simulate what databases do with indexes, because it is very fast to search something in a sorted list.

The first list should be sorted the `From` property, and the hash into the second list, sorted by the `To` property. This would be similar to what a database does.

**Sorted Lists in .Net**

.Net has a class to make both keyed and positional access called [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx), that you can use to achieve what you want.

You can use the constructor that takes an `IComparer` that you can use to indicate how the SortedList should compare your `Restriction` class. You will need to code two IComparers, one that compares the From property, and another one that compares the To property.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of queries and not so many inserts you could do the following:
Create two sorted Lists of your Objects, one sorted by `fromDate` the other by `toDate`. Then you can do fast Searches on the sortedLists to find for each List, the set of valid results (in the first list you query for entries with `fromDate <= searchDate` and in the second list you query for `toDate >= searchDate`). Then join the result sets to obtain the results.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to this kind of problem is to implement partitioning; this is implemented in database environments to reduce search space. The only caveat is that your collection can't be filtered with other criteria or you'll need to build an index.

A sample implementation might utilize a set of lists that contain certain date ranges (by month(s), year(s), etc). When you perform insertions, you determine the correct list and place your item in that list. When you perform a search, you can easily determine the correct list or set of lists, and then only perform a scan in those lists.

However, you should also consider this -- how many elements will you be dealing with? Scanning an entire list only becomes a serious problem when the number of elements is very large. Optimizing this problem would be premature if you're not dealing with exorbitant amounts of data.